# php setcookie() not working correct

Tags: php, forms, setcookie

I'm trying to get the hang of how setcookie() works in php so i made i simple script for testing purposes. The only thing the script does is ask for a username and then makes a cookie for it. when you enter the same username again it should welcome you back. if it is the first time you entered that username it should welcome you for the first time. Here's what i did:

This is the form;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<title>XXL Computer winkel</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>php lab 12</h3>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 >
<form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<tr>
<td>gebruikersnaam</td>
<td><input type="text" name="user" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="send" value="inloggen" /> </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php

include ("cookiefuncties.php");

welkom();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

cookiefuncties.php looks like this:

```
<?php

function welkom()
{

if(isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $cookie_value = $_POST['user'];
    $cookie_name = "gebruikersnaam";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
}
if(isset($_POST['user'])&& $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] === ($_POST['user']))
    {

        echo "Welcome back " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] . "!";
    }
if(isset($_POST['user'])&& $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] != ($_POST['user']))
    {

        echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] . "This is your first visit";
    }
}

?>
```

Problem is that the cookie is always 'one name late'. Therefore i need to refresh the page and it will always welcome the user back instead of saying it's the first visit. I know there is an option to 'force' a refresh but i don't know how, and if that is the solution.

Greetings,
Lennart

ps. Don't mind the spacings. I still don't know how to get that right on this site :-(

Comment: you have to change the cookie name per user and at every request before setting cookie for that user you have to check for existence of cookie.

Comment: Am i not doing that already? If i log in with a different name and refresh i get the new name. It's just that i want it to work without the refresh

Comment: Your scenerio is something like follow 1st user enters name and click submit  you have to check whether username is already enter or not and show appropriate message?

Comment: try to use below answer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep a cookie for each user. Just set a cookie with value `true` for each new user. Try this code in your `cookiefuncties.php` :

```
<?php

function welkom() {

    if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $cookie_name = $_POST['user'];
        setcookie($cookie_name, true, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
        if( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && true == $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) {
            echo "Welcome back " . $_POST['user'] . "!";
        } else {
            echo "Welcome " . $_POST['user'] . "This is your first visit";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the respons! This Works :-) One thing though. If a name (For instance Giel)  is set for the first time i also get Notice: Undefined index: Giel in C:\xampp\htdocs\unit4\cookiefuncties.php on line 8

Comment: @Lennart you're right. :-) I didn't have warnings enabled so that's why I did not get that. I updated the code. Please try again.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for your valuable help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set the unique name per user  cookie and check it exist or not.

```
   if(isset($_POST['user']) and !empty($_POST['user']))
   {

       $user = $_POST['user'];
       // set the unique cookie name
       $cookie_name = "gebruikersnaam_$user";    
       $setCookie = true;

       if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) and $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $user )
       {
           echo "Welcome Back ".$user;
       }else
       {
           echo "This is your first visit $user";
       }

       setcookie($cookie_name, $user, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 

   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the resons! If i paste this in my function i get errors. because $user requires the form to be submitted. I did however added a line to my script;    $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value; which makes it now possible to directly after submitting post the name. Problem still is that it always "Welcomes the name back", even when it's typed in for the first time.